# SQLException - JDBC Driver & Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, rest, servlets

I'm trying to learn Android and Servlet programming and having trouble connecting to a local mySQL database. I have a simple Android client that does a HTTPpost request to a servlet thats hosted on localhost. The request seems to be working fine, but the servlet is having trouble locating the Driver for the database. I'm pretty sure the mysql url is correct so I'm guessing its the Driver that's the problem!

This is the utility class that should get the connection to the database:

```
public class Database {

private static Connection connection = null;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static Connection getConnection(){
    if(connection!=null){
        return connection;
    } else {
        try {
            Properties db_properties = new Properties();
            InputStream inStream = Database.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
            db_properties.load(inStream);
            String dbDriver = db_properties.getProperty("dbDriver");
            String url = db_properties.getProperty("url");
            String dbUser = db_properties.getProperty("dbUser");
            String dbPass = db_properties.getProperty("dbPassword");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbUser,dbPass);
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

This is the following Database properties file:

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/gymbuddy
user=Mathan
pass=PYCCmcPDAFSj7N9B
```

This is the how the servlet setup looks like:

[image: Servlet Setup]

And this is the stack trace I get:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/gymbuddy?user=Mathan&password=PYCCmcPDAFSj7N9B
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at com.mathanv.gb.util.Database.getConnection(Database.java:36)
        at com.mathanv.gb.dao.BuddyDao.<init>(BuddyDao.java:35)
        at com.mathanv.gb.controller.BuddyController.<init>(BuddyController.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1137)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Mar 2, 2013 11:50:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [BuddyController] in context with path [/gbserver] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mathanv.gb.dao.BuddyDao.registerBuddy(BuddyDao.java:44)
        at com.mathanv.gb.controller.BuddyController.doPost(BuddyController.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Help!

If you need any more information, let me know!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your driver Class before attempting to get a connection

```
Class.forName(dbDriver); // before
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbUser,dbPass); //after
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that sorted out that exception! Can't believe I didn't notice that. But getting new errors now (Edited original post with new errors)

Comment: That's because your property is called `driver`, but you're trying to get it with the key `dbDriver` You need to use the name of the key in the properties file.

Comment: made the changes and still getting the exception. Tried putting the string directly as an argument as well and still got the same error.

Comment: You have to do it for all your properties.